# Is there a way to count(comment) to get the correct total, then filter WHERE comment =?

Tags: neo4j

I am adding functionality to return only the comments that the user was mentioned in with `WHERE comment.text =~ { mention }`. While this correctly returns the mentioned comments, the `commentsCount` becomes # mentioned comments, when I would like total # comments. Is there a way I can count `commentsCount` as # total comments, before applying `WHERE comment.text =~ { mention }`?

```
// MENTIONS

  MATCH (user:User {user_id: { user_id }})

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
  WHERE post.createdAt < { before } AND post.text =~ { keyword }

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT user.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id AND comment.text =~ { mention }  // filter

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    max(comment.createdAt) as commentCreatedAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter
  ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentsCount,
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, commentCreatedAt, commentsCount: commentsPerCommenter}) as commentAuthors

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentsCount,  // incorrect # mentioned comments only, want # total comments
    size(commentAuthors) as participantsCount,
    commentAuthors

  UNWIND commentAuthors as commentAuthor

  RETURN collect(post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    notificationType: 'mention'
  })[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this query might do the trick:

EDIT

Added calculation of participants before the filtering. This uses [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension), paired with `apoc.coll.toSet()` from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) in order to ensure the list only has distinct values (otherwise you would get multiple occurrences of the same commenter, once for every comment in the post).

```
  // MENTIONS

  MATCH (user:User {user_id: { user_id }})

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
  WHERE post.createdAt < { before } AND post.text =~ { keyword }

  // get total comments per post
  WITH 
   post, 
   author, 
   user, 
   size((post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()) as commentsCount,
   size(apoc.coll.toSet(
     [(post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor) 
       WHERE author <> commentAuthor | commentAuthor])) as participantsCount

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor)
  WHERE user <> commentAuthor AND comment.text =~ { mention }  // filter

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    commentAuthor,
    max(comment.createdAt) as commentCreatedAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter

  ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, commentCreatedAt, commentsCount: commentsPerCommenter}) as commentAuthors

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentsCount,  
    participantsCount,
    commentAuthors

  UNWIND commentAuthors as commentAuthor

  RETURN collect(post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    notificationType: 'mention'
  })[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

Comment: After staring at it for a bit trying to make sense of what numbers this was giving me, this seems to return the count of the # comments the mentioner made in the post, rather than the # total comments all users made in the post.

Comment: Got it, edited my query to calculate total comments count per post sooner, before we actually match to the comments.

Comment: Hi, super close! This returns the correct # total comments, however the participantsCount is still incorrect as # of users who mentioned you because this happens after the filter. That's cool, I didn't know you could size a relationship in a WITH like that `size((post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()) as commentsCount`. I tried doing something like: `size((post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()<-[:AUTHOR]-()) as participantsCount`, but that returned the # total comments.

Comment: Do you also want the `commentCreatedAt` field to be before the filtering, or after?

Comment: That can be after filtering because it's meant to be the time that the single comment mentioning the user was posted. I am not having any trouble with that field, however. It seems to return the expected result.

Comment: Still stuck here with the incorrect `participantsCount`. :) I haven't seen the pattern `size((post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()) as commentsCount` before. Because this returned the correct `commentsCount`, I was wondering why I couldn't do: `size((post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->()<-[:AUTHOR]-()) as participantsCount`, since the solution probably has to do getting `participantsCount` before filtering.

Comment: While you could use `size()` with that pattern, that will look for all occurrences of the pattern, so the same commenters will be counted multiple times for each of their comments on the post. If you have access to APOC Procedures, we can use a combination of pattern comprehension and a procedure to remove duplicates from a collection, then take the size of the collection.

Comment: First time hearing about APOC. I'm using GrapheneDB, so I can use http://docs.graphenedb.com/v1.0/docs/stored-procedures#section-adding-apoc to add them it seems. UPDATE: Okay, I have APOC now! (even though it's only been a few months and I barely know Cypher alone...)

Comment: Great! Updated my answer accordingly (participantsCount is calculated in the same part of the query as commentsCount)

Comment: Wow APOC is badass and you sir r badass. Will reward bounty when I can. Thanks again, learned a lot of new Neo4j tricks with my recent questions and best of all, my Posts/Comments are pretty much done and all working as intended. ^^